# How do I find out why certain ports are excluded and delete the exclusion?

Tags: windows, port

After a recent Windows update I can no longer listen on port 1433 (I have SQL server running remotely and tunnel to it).

After much googling I found the reason is that those ports have been "excluded"

```
PS C:\Windows\system32>  netsh int ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp

Protocol tcp Port Exclusion Ranges

Start Port    End Port
----------    --------
      1114        1213
      1214        1313
      1414        1513
      1514        1613
      1614        1713
      2000        2099
     25173       25272
     50000       50059     *

* - Administered port exclusions.
```

When I try to delete the exclusion:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> netsh int ipv4 delete excludedportrange protocol=tcp 1414 1000
Element not found.
```

How can I find out why those ports are excluded and "un-exclude" them?

I have Windows 10 Home 2004.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be due to a Windows update or enabling Hyper-V (which I think was the cause for me).

https://dandini.wordpress.com/2019/07/15/administered-port-exclusions-blocking-high-ports/

I saved the script as a batch file, ran it and it resolved my issue.

It seems like you may be able to run the following command instead of the entire script:

reg add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\hns\State /v EnableExcludedPortRange /d 0 /f

https://superuser.com/questions/1579346/many-excludedportranges-how-to-delete-hyper-v-is-disabled

Answer (score 0):

The answer is posted in a related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48478869/cannot-bind-to-some-ports-due-to-permission-denied/62359555#62359555
by @onoma

Basically you just need to run
`netsh int ipv4 set dynamic tcp start=49152 num=16384` and restart